# Programmatically push history in React Route 4, Switch not updating

Tags: react-router

I was experimenting with React router 4 to make sure I could programmatically change routes using `router.history.push` from my top level App. For example, if I need to do so after an async action, etc. The mui App renders a Wrapper, which displays an AppBar and Drawer/Menu, then renders its children which is a single `<Switch>` element in this case. The App grabs the router from context (I know I could use withRouter, but I was just trying this out). If the Menu internally uses `<Link>` elements, it works as expected and the Switch displays the expected route. However, if the menu dispatches routes to the App, and it pushes them via the router, then the URL changes but the switch does NOT update, even though the Wrapper.render is called.

I recreated the situation in this sandbox, where the Menu for Page 2 uses a Link, but the Home and Page 1 items dispatch the routes up to the App. In looking at the source for `Router.Link`, it seems to ultimately be doing the same thing my App is doing (get Router via context and push), so I am trying to understand what is going on. Here is the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/olnp135zmy

Thanks!